# How to see the loaded kernel modules on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, linux-kernel

In Linux we have the `lsmod`. What is the equivalent of `lsmod` in Mac?

Comment: Because `lsmod` is a command specific to the Linux Kernel and Mac OS is not Linux.

Comment: It helps to understand that programs such as that are external utilities and not commands provided by the shell.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As documented here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html

"`lsmod` is not available on Mac OS X, but other commands exist that offer similar functionality."  They list `kextutil`, `kextstat`, `kextload`, `kmodunload` (I think they mean `kextunload`).  These commands have `man` pages on Mac OS X.

Comment: That a link is dead now, do you have any idea where I can find the same document today?

Comment: Updated.  Apple likes to shuffle things around. :)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to know what kernel extensions are loaded on MacOS you use the `kextstat` command.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, the manpages for `kextstat`, `kextutil`, `kextload`, and `kextunload` mention that they are deprecated, and instead recommend `kmutil`.  To replicate behavior for `kextstat`, use `kmutil showloaded`.